# Show that any harmonic map $f:\Sigma_1 \rightarrow \Sigma_2$ is a constant.

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be Riemann surfaces with nonnegative and negative curvature respectively. Show that any harmonic map $f:\Sigma_1 \rightarrow \Sigma_2$ is a constant.

---

Thanks to the comment of Anthony Carapetis, it follows from Bochner identity and Riemann-Hurwitz that $f$ must be a constant.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Bochner identity for harmonic maps?